# Tensorflow, Keras: How to solve "Dimension must be equal, but are ..." errors in general

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, lstm, dataflow

often during working with tensorflow & keras, I receive shape error like:

```
Dimensions must be equal, but are 24 and 48 for '{{node Equal}} = Equal[T=DT_FLOAT, incompatible_shape_error=true](Cast_1, Cast_2)' with input shapes: [?,24], [?,48].
```

To solve these issues, I normally look into my net, try to see how the data flows and where it breaks and fix it. But I am missing tools, that might help me to find out, which layer / function does cause the exception. Currently it feels like stigging in the dark. So I am looking for a more professional way to solve these issues by tracking the data flow, so I can see which layer / function causes it. Do you have any advice?

For example, this is the model which causes the error above:

```
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Concatenate
from attention_layer import AttentionLayer

encoder_inputs = keras.layers.Input(shape=[pad_len], dtype=np.int32,name="encoder_inputs")
decoder_inputs = keras.layers.Input(shape=[pad_len], dtype=np.int32, name="decoder_inputs")
condi_input = keras.layers.Input(shape=[1], dtype=np.int32, name="condi_input")
class_input = keras.layers.Input(shape=[1], dtype=np.int32, name="class_input")


embeddings = keras.layers.Embedding(vocab_size, 10)
encoder_embeddings_1 = embeddings(encoder_inputs)
decoder_embeddings_1 = embeddings(decoder_inputs)

embeddings2 = keras.layers.Embedding(vocab_size, 10)
encoder_embeddings_2 = embeddings2(encoder_inputs)
decoder_embeddings_2 = embeddings2(decoder_inputs)

encoder_embeddings = keras.layers.concatenate([encoder_embeddings_1, encoder_embeddings_2] ,axis=1)
decoder_embeddings = keras.layers.concatenate([decoder_embeddings_2, decoder_embeddings_2], axis=1)

encoder_1 = keras.layers.LSTM(64, return_sequences=True, return_state=True)
encoder_lstm_bidirectional_1 = keras.layers.Bidirectional(encoder_1)(encoder_embeddings)
encoder_2 = keras.layers.LSTM(64, return_sequences=True, return_state=True)
encoder_lstm_bidirectional_2 = keras.layers.Bidirectional(encoder_2)(encoder_lstm_bidirectional_1)
encoder_3 = keras.layers.LSTM(64, return_sequences=True, return_state=True)
encoder_lstm_bidirectional_3 = keras.layers.Bidirectional(encoder_3)(encoder_lstm_bidirectional_2)
encoder_4 = keras.layers.LSTM(64, return_sequences=True, return_state=True)
encoder_lstm_bidirectional_4 = keras.layers.Bidirectional(encoder_4)

encoder_output, state_h1, state_c1, state_h2, state_c2 = encoder_lstm_bidirectional_4(encoder_lstm_bidirectional_3)
encoder_state = [Concatenate()([state_h1, state_h2]), Concatenate()([state_c1, state_c2])]


decoder_lstm = keras.layers.LSTM(64*2, return_sequences=True, return_state=True, name="decoder_lstm")
decoder_outputs,decoder_fwd_state, decoder_back_state = decoder_lstm(decoder_embeddings,initial_state=encoder_state)
attn_layer = AttentionLayer(name="attention_layer")
attn_out, attn_states = attn_layer([encoder_output, decoder_outputs])

decoder_concat_input = Concatenate(axis=-1, name="decoder_concat_layer")([decoder_outputs, attn_out, tf.cast(tf.broadcast_to(condi_input, shape=tf.shape(decoder_outputs)), dtype=tf.float32), tf.cast(tf.broadcast_to(class_input, shape=tf.shape(decoder_outputs)), dtype=tf.float32)])

decoder_dense_out = keras.layers.TimeDistributed(keras.layers.Dense(vocab_size, activation="softmax"))
decoder_outputs = decoder_dense_out(decoder_concat_input)

model = keras.Model(inputs=[encoder_inputs, decoder_inputs, condi_input, class_input], outputs=[decoder_outputs])
```

Thanks!

Comment: Is your issue resolved now? Else, please can you share reproducible code to replicate your issue or colab link.

Comment: The issue is not solved, as there still in no general answer to my question. My question is pointing at a general method, the code I showed was just an example. Its not about a specific issue.